# Offline Bootstrap IGNORED By Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask site running on a raspberry pi, and I implemented some bootstrap stuff to make it look better. However, the pi is running an access point, so it cant connect to the internet to include the bootstrap files. So, I downloaded the Bootstrap files and placed it into the folder with the python script, and the flask templates folder. NOT INSIDE the templates folder, since I see thats a common mistake. When I open the html file raw in a browser, it displays perfectly, using bootstrap, but when I start the flask site and test it again, it displays the site as if the bootstrap files doesn't exist!
How can this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default Flask configuration, [you will need to place static files in the `static` directory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/) within your project and refer to them via `/static/...`.

Comment: Do I just put the whole bootstrap folder in another folder named "static"?

Comment: That should work. You will just need to also change the references in your templates - see the link!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a *static* folder in your application which will hold all your styling needs.

Within that folder, add your bootstrap files. In your templates, properly create a link to the bootstrap files:

```py
$ <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename = '<your-bootstrap-file>') }}">
```